# "Warning the partition is misaligned by 3072 bytes" Centos 6 10TB non boot drive, how do I fix?

Tags: linux, partition, dd

I was very careful installing the and and going through the format guides
but in the Disk Analyzer it says the following?

[image]

how do i fix it? Its not a boot drive so I understand  I can commands from the CLI ?

Thank you in advance.

I googled for an answer they directed to several people asking the same questions without an direct answer.

```
 fdisk -l /dev/sdb

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 10000.8 GB, 10000831348736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1215865 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 10000.8 GB, 10000831348736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1215865 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
[root@server ~]# gdisk -l /dev/sdb
-bash: gdisk: command not found
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` (copy to the question, please).

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/201164/proper-alignment-of-partitions-on-an-advanced-format-hdd-using-parted  & https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_4_KiB_sector_issues & https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-4kb-sector-disks/

Comment: 10000831314432 bytes is not a multiple of 4096, so you need to insert unused space of an appropriate amount before the partition, of several KB - you can easily compute the appropriate amount. Aligning all partitions on MiB multiples solves this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks Issac i pasted the output of the results to the question

Comment: The partition listed by `fdisk` is not a real partition, but an attempt at a "protective MBR partition". Your disk is partitioned using the GPT scheme, and as the warning message says, your version of fdisk does not support GPT. This is not a real problem though, the fake MBR is not used for anything. As others have said, you need to repartition the disk so that the partitions are aligned at multiples of 4096.

Comment: Since your `fdisk` does not support GPT, use `gdisk` instead. What is the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: Kamil i added the output to the answer

Comment: The problem of alignment is reported by fdisk (from the output you posted). An start on sector 1 is quite unusual and strongly not recommended.The error reported of sector boundary could be safely ignored. But fdisk also hints to the fact that this is an GPT partitioned disk. You should use diferent tools in this case. A tool similar to fdisk for GPT disks is gdisk. But honestly, what you should do is use gparted (or similar) and re-partition the disk, it will take care of the correct start sector.

Comment: @user3265051 Sorry but you copiedthe output of `fdisk` (not `gdisk`) again to the question. Please review and correct. :-)

Comment: `-bash: gdisk: command not found` is a message from Bash saying `gdisk` was not found. Maybe you need to install it. Alternatively use another partitioning tool that is able to print the GPT using sectors as the unit.